# Custom error message for integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert, unique-constraint

Any ideas on how to create a custom error message for an integrity constraint violation when the INSERT INTO includes a foreach loop?

```
$states is an array;
$franchise_id is an integer;
```

Query:

```
public static function update($franchise_id, $states)
{

    try
    {
        // establish db connection
        $db = static::getDB();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO franchise_states SET
                state_id     = :state_id,
                franchise_id = :franchise_id";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($states as $state)
        {
            $stmt->execute([':state_id' => $state, ':franchise_id' => $franchise_id]);
        }
        return $stmt;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
       echo "Error updating franchise data: " . $e->getMessage();
       exit();
    }
}
```

I'd like to add something like this--

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'alert("State already included.")';
echo '</script>';
```

--so the user can stay on the same page.

Solutions in the catch block like this:

```
if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 23000) {
    ....
}
```

are not working. Perhaps because the error is thrown after the loops first iteration.

Neither is this:

```
foreach($states as $state)
{
    $result = $stmt->execute([':state_id' => $state, ':franchise_id' => $franchise_id]);
    if (!result) 
    {
        ...
    }    
}
```

When the loop runs its first iteration it appears to encounter the constraint violation, so the code after that isn't executed. Not sure if that's what actually happening however.

It seems like inserting a custom error message must be possible. I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions if anyone knows how.

Error:

```
Fatal error
Uncaught exception: 'PDOException'

Message: 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5-1' for key 'franchise_state_id''

Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\agt\App\Models\Franchise_state.php(69): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\agt\App\Controllers\Admin\Franchisors.php(336): App\Models\Franchise_state::update('5', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\agt\Core\Router.php(206): App\Controllers\Admin\Franchisors->update()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\agt\public\index.php(162): Core\Router->dispatch('admin/franchiso...')
#4 {main}
```

Comment: please share complete error

Comment: Are you using namespaces? Did you mean to use `\PDOException` ?

Comment: Why do you think the error code depends on which iteration it is? The error is thrown as soon as an error is detected. What is the actual value of `$e->errorInfo`?

Comment: @Ravi thanks `Fatal error
Uncaught exception: 'PDOException'

Message: 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5-1' for key 'franchise_state_id''`

Comment: Please update to original post

Comment: @Evert Yes. Using namespaces.

Comment: So did you `use` PDOException? Or try `\PDOException` ?

Comment: @Evert I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you use namespaces, you need to import the PDOException class. Reading up on PHP namespaces might help. Since you don't understand my question, I think it's highly likely this is your problem. To try it out, just replace `catch (PDOException $e)` with `catch (\PDOException $e)`

Comment: @Evert you're right that I'm not expert in namespace nuance. I did add the no namespace slash in front of the class  earlier, and it throws the same error. Since my desire to figure out a way to stop the error process in order to introduce an alert seems especially difficult, I decided to take another route, viz. to remove the constraint and then write a query to check if any array element-franchise_id pair are already in the table. I wrote that code and it works, so I will have to abandon my original intent. Thank you for taking the time to review my question. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5-1' for key
>   'franchise_state_id''

Indicates unique key violation, and `franchise_state_id` column doesn't allow duplicate values. If duplicate value is expected in `franchise_state_id`, then you need to alter you table to remove unique constraint from `franchise_state_id` column.

But, if it expected to store unique value, then you need to make changes to application to make sure, you don't pass duplicate entry (validate if entry already exists from database).

Comment: I need the constraints because to update the table using a foreach loop I must use `INSERT INTO` rather than `UPDATE`. To remove the constraint allows duplication. The issue I am now trying to resolve is the next step in the process. I want to catch the duplication and alert the user.

Comment: @JimB814 I didn't get you. So, basically, you wanted to show user, if entry is duplicate ?

Comment: @JimB814 just for your info, I didn't said, you need to `update` rather than `insert` instead, I said, if you are expecting duplicate then remove constraint. But, you said, you aren't expecting duplicate, so, this option rules out now.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I wanted to let you know the evolution. It's an update functionality, but because the values are coming in an array `UPDATE` didn't work. It over-wrote the update each time so that the last element of the array became the value of each record. I then attempted to develop a query to check if the values already existed, but I have written so many tests that I can't recall exactly where that was failing before moving on the current idea of displaying an alert after the constraint triggers an error. If I could stop the code at the error, I could show the alert.

Comment: Ravi. I took your advice to remove the constraint and write validation code to check if an array element-franchise_id pair was already in the database. I did that and the code works. This is a solution, though it isn't the solution I sought when I posted the question. I'm more than fine with this solution, however, because it does what I need it to do. Thanks for taking the time to review my question and for your alternative solution.

Comment: @JimB814 If it does what you wanted and it is your solution, then you need to mark it accepted.

Comment: I can argue that it was helpful more than that it answered the question as asked. But given the fact that your suggestion to take a different approach ended up guiding me to a solution, I can also argue that your answer did provide a solution. Thanks for the solution!